# Refer to time series object by column name

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following `test` data frame :

```
test <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
    a      b      c      d      e
-0.67  -0.02  -0.1   -0.22  -0.32
 0.46  -1.51  -0.79   0.26   1.19
 0.22  -0.18  -1.4    0.41  -0.32
-2.21   0.79   0.36   1.    -0.51
-0.69   0.39  -0.76  -0.73  -0.43
-0.45  -1.33   0.15  -2.23  -0.58
")
```

In this format, I can easily access the columns using the `test$b` notation. I can convert this to a time series object without difficulty:

```
test.ts <- ts(test, frequency=<value>, start=<value>
```

However, once it's a `ts` object, is there any easy way to access the columns (or rows) by name instead of by column number? The `test.ts` object still has the column name information, shown by using `colnames`:

```
> colnames(test.ts)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

However, `test.ts$b` doesn't work. Note that by "easily" I mean without writing something ugly like `test.ts[,which(colnames(test.ts)=="b"]`, because that's not easy, that's ugly. Yes, I could write my own function to do that, but I was wondering whether there's a built-in way to do this.

Comment: Instead of just displaying `test` it would be easier for us if you showed the output of the command `dput(head(test))`. That way, we can just cut and paste it into our R sessions.

Comment: @nograpes - Added. Never knew about that command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the other subsetting syntax:

```
test.ts[, 'b']
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 6 
#Frequency = 1 
#[1] -0.02 -1.51 -0.18  0.79  0.39 -1.33
```

Comment: I didn't even know there *was* another subsetting syntax. Thanks!

Comment: `?ts` says that a `ts` object is really just a `vector` or `matrix` with some extra attributes.  You can see that `class(unclass(test.ts))` is `matrix`.  So, you can subset it like a `matrix` (that has `colnames`)