# How to name columns in time series objects?

Tags: r, time-series

I am a bit puzzled here and must be missing something quite basic. 
I want to extract columns from a multiple time series object. It can perhaps be done by making the ts object into a dataframe and then extracting them, but there is a direct way of subsetting time series as given in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542584/refer-to-time-series-object-by-column-name)

To figure out how to assign names to ts objects, ?ts shows

```
ts(data = NA, start = 1, end = numeric(), frequency = 1,
   deltat = 1, ts.eps = getOption("ts.eps"), class = , names = )
```

but on running the code in ?ts help, with or without the names parameter gives 
`names(z)` NULL.

`z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start=c(1961, 1), frequency=12)`
or `z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start=c(1961, 1), frequency=12, names=c("x1", "x2", "x3"))`

Main question: 1. How does one assign names to columns in time series objects ts and mts ?
2. What are the methods of extracting columns directly from time series object along with the time index? Is it necessary to convert it to zoo or xts class? or add the time index separately?

To give an idea of problem I am trying to solve:

```
# using inbuilt ldeaths time series dataset
ldeaths
d <- diff(ldeaths)
percen <- quantile(d, 0.9)
i <- ifelse(d>percen, 1,0)
signal <- cbind(d,i)
```

Now to extract the dataset for which the indicator is 1, *with the time index*,
I am not sure how to proceed. str(signal) is an mts object but printing signal shows no time index.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any thoughts on why printing signal does not give the time information alongside the data although it is an mts object ?

Comment: It does, what do you think the `rownames` on the printed object are!? This is standard behaviour for `"ts"` objects. The `tsp(obj)` of `"ts" object `obj` are only explicitly printed if the data are not annual, quaterly or monthly. In those three special cases, the `print.ts` method prefers a more compact layout that some consider more useful. You can always get the time information from `tsp(signal)` assuming that is what you mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Extracting the names of series in an `"mts"` object

You want `colnames()`:

```
> colnames(z)
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"
```

This is because `z` is actually a matrix with extra attributes and matrices don't have `names` but they do have `colnames`.

### Assigning/changing the names of series in an `"mts"` object

To assign `colnames` after the fact or to change them use the replacement function `'colnames<-'`

```
> colnames(z) <- paste0("a", 1:3)
> colnames(z)
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

### Extracting a particular series from an `"mts"` object

As for extracting columns, `[` works just fine for `"ts"` and `"mts"` objects. for example:

```
> z[,1]
             Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May
1961  0.81800833 -0.30852155  0.05915071  0.14937058  0.67734362
1962  1.12993606 -0.81176485 -0.51903387  1.12527537 -0.34377553
1963  1.30469813  0.32486340  0.01029512 -1.13631688 -1.22013150
1964  0.72449621 -0.88704234  0.78834391 -0.92956537 -0.31584252
1965  0.24610412  0.97980266  0.17136276  2.45216318  0.15846038
1966 -0.48891587 -0.62820331  0.33190472  2.14094813  1.32389152
1967  0.49120472 -0.10149521 -0.39070688 -0.78743955 -1.20563040
1968 -0.70749150  0.52333087 -0.51991721  0.02037504 -0.59848254
1969 -0.80156968 -1.38172513  0.09400527  0.66966443            
....
```

### The guts of the OP's problem

For the last bit, I'm not sure what you hope to get. A `"ts"` or `"mts"` object is a regular time series and extracting the bits of `signal[, "d"]` results in a vector not a time series.

```
> signal[signal[,2] == 1, 1]
[1]  761 1104  810  653  522  956  593
```

There *isn't* any time index because this is no longer a `"ts"` object. If you want to do this, the **zoo** package is probably the way you want to go. Here is an example, where we convert to zoo object using `as.zoo()`

```
require(zoo)
sz <- as.zoo(signal)
```

Then we can extract the observations we want (the names on which are a useful indicator of the time index)

```
> sz[sz[, "i"] == 1, "d"]
1975(12)  1976(2) 1976(12) 1977(12)  1978(1) 1978(12)  1979(1) 
     761     1104      810      653      522      956      593
```

and then a similar subsetting call but using the `index()` to return the time index of the entire zoo object and then select out the bits we want

```
> index(sz)[sz[, "i"] == 1]
[1] 1975.917 1976.083 1976.917 1977.917 1978.000 1978.917
[7] 1979.000
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply! I want to extract the dates for which the values exceed the percentile. I tried other ways of combining the signal with the data like merge to keep it as ts object. It kind of gets confusing when moving between zoo and ts and dataframe objects and therefore wondering if there is a direct way using ts class only.

Comment: From your example, the `index(sz)` (from my Answer) and `tsp(signal)` (from your Question) seem very similar. Not sure what you mean is confusing from the **zoo** side of things.

Comment: I was trying a similar subsetting method but it was not working. It takes time to figure out how to read in data as zoo object. And after that, some combining method or analysis will change the object properties and then it is not clear how to reassign it back , with say index or attributes.

Comment: Is there a way of interpreting the index values given in index(sz) as 1975.917, 1976.083,...

Comment: They are proportions of the frequency (1/12). Try `setNames((1:12) / 12, month.abb)` to see what the decimals mean. In my Answer, the `names(sz[sz[, "i"] == 1, "d"])` contains the month in `()` which also helps you know what the decimals mean in terms of months.

Comment: Also, @Anusha if you are happy with an Answer on [so] please consider accepting it. The [ask] section of the FAQ indicates why this is useful and helpful for the site and other users, and how to accept answers to questions. Essentially just check the big tick mark next to the answer you wish to accept.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19244/discussion-between-anusha-and-gavin-simpson)

Comment: Is there now a problem with the Answer? Why did you unaccept?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename your `mts` (matrix time series) object's column. Just simply using `colnames()` function.

For example: You have a time series data containing three column and you want to change that column name:

```
colnames(data) <- c('newname1','newname2','newname3')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As simple as that