# How to extract time attributes for a univariate time series?

Tags: r

How can I convert a simple time series object to be of dimensions 2 by adding time attributes so that colnames can be used?

## Edit :

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278972/how-to-name-columns-in-time-series-objects), the way to refer to time series was to use colnames and suggested method was to convert it to zoo objects. In case of single time series, if I do names(tseries), it gives NULL. So to assign the names, tried using colnames which can only be used in objects of dimension 2 and constructed by adding index of dates. Here I am trying to use the time attributes already there in the list object so that I dont have to convert back and forth from zoo objects.

If there is an alternative I will be very happy to know that. The purpose is to be able to use the name of the time series in title of plots etc.

## Edit 2:

To rephrase the question, how to give name to a time series ? Using apply strips the time series attributes as asked in many questions here. Then to get back the time attributes and the name, and in a format which allows using colnames, what are the methods ? I started with series and a column of dates which allowed naming the series but in a vector format returned from the lapply(tslist, function), I need to reallocate the names. If there is a simpler way to do this, please do let me know as that is the main problem.

A somewhat related question is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878615/format-a-zoo-object-with-dimnames-list-of-2) where answer by @Henrik suggests adding a dummy column to avoid coercion of zoo object to a vector to keep the it of dimension 2.

In a specific situation where we have a list object with required time info, I followed this method.

When using HP filter to find the cycle, I do the following

```
x <-ts(rnorm(100), start = c(1990, 1), frequency = 12)

library(mFilter)
hp <- hpfilter(x, 1600)
c1 <- hp$cycle

str(c1)
 #Time-Series [1:100] from 1990 to 1998: 1.852 -0.368 -0.942 -0.756 1.006 ...

str(hp) # shows that it has the attributes of time series and tsp etc.
```

Str of main object from which subsetting is

```
List of 10
 $ cycle  : Time-Series [1:100] from 1990 to 1998: 1.852 -0.368 -0.942 -0.756 1.006 ...
 $ trend  : ts [1:100, 1] -0.191 -0.193 -0.193 -0.191 -0.187 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "Series 1"
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12
 $ fmatrix: num [1:100, 1:100] 0.799 -0.178 -0.156 -0.135 -0.116 ...
 $ title  : chr "Hodrick-Prescott Filter"
 $ xname  : chr "x"
 $ call   : language hpfilter(x = x, freq = 1600)
 $ type   : chr "lambda"
 $ lambda : num 1600
 $ method : chr "hpfilter"
 $ x      : ts [1:100, 1] 1.661 -0.561 -1.135 -0.947 0.819 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "Series 1"
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "mFilter"
```

c1 is an object of dimension 1 because when I try to assign it a name,

```
colnames(c1) <- "x"
```

gives this error

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "iip") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

To help use name of time series, we can either convert c1 to a zoo object by adding an index or cbind it with a column of dates.

Since the name and time attributes information is there in the starting object from which we are subsetting, is there a way to use it to extract a component with the time attributes ?

## Edit :

The extracted series must have structure like that of inputted series which is there in the list object

```
ts [1:100, 1] 1.661 -0.561 -1.135 -0.947 0.819 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "Series 1"
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12
```

which I think can be accessed as

```
attributes(c1) <- attributes(hp$x)

colnames(c1) <- "X1"  # is now possible.
```

How can I return hp$cycle along with its attributes ?

How can I access chr "Series 1" when allocating colnames ?

```
colnames(c1) 

# Series 1
```

## Edit :

```
## Return hp$cycle along with the time attributes so that str(h1) is as follows

h1 <- hp$cycle
str(h1)
# this gives 
Time-Series [1:100] from 1990 to 1998: 1.852 -0.368 -0.942 -0.756 1.006 ..
#I want it to be of this form 

ts [1:100, 1] 1.661 -0.561 -1.135 -0.947 0.819 ...
      ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. ..$ : NULL
      .. ..$ : chr "Series 1"
      ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12
```

Thanks a lot.

## Edit :

These are the alternatives I used to extract the time attributes from one series and add to another series.

1. Using tsp : 
   This was giving error or dimension mismatch

   tsp(h1) <- tsp(x)
2. Using start, end, frequency information in tsp 
   Since tsp for monthly data is in fractions, didnt know how to get the starting month info 
   i.e. converting  1970.250 to 1970, 4 say, (dont know which is the starting month)
   Then I could do something like

   h1.ts <- ts(h1, start =c(tsp [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278972/how-to-name-columns-in-time-series-objects), n), frequency = tsp[3])

Comment: `c1` is not a matrix, it is a `ts` object. You cannot use `colnames`. `attr(c1,"dimnames")[[2]]` gives `"Series 1"`.

Comment: I'm still not clear on this, but you can access `"Series 1"` with `attributes(hp$trend)$dimnames[[2]]`.  Does that help?

Comment: Can you then suggest an alternative by which I can allocate name to the series which can be used in a list of series or title in plots? When I do names(tseries), it gives NULL.

Comment: @Anusha I am not sure what your expected result is. Does this help ? `attributes(c1) <- attributes(hp$trend); colnames(c1)#[1] "Series 1"`

Comment: @akrun Thanks. This helps but it doesnt have the time series object. Is there a way to get the ts data along with the attributes ? i.e. hp$trend along with the attributes. I hope the context of the question is clear with the recent edits and main question to allow access to the name of the time series.

Comment: How can I return hp$trend and hp$cycle along with its time attributes ?

Comment: @Anusha Did you mean `cycle`, `trend` etc or the attributes for object `x`?

Comment: @akrun cycle and trend both. hp$cycle and hp$trend. I thought it would be the same method for both.

Comment: @akrun I want to get hp$cycle and hp$trend in such a way that when I do str(hp$cycle), I get 
ts [1:100, 1] 1.852 -0.368 -0.942 -0.756 1.006 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "Series 1"
  ..- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12

Comment: @Anusha  Can you paste that in your post?  It is hard to understand from the comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61471/discussion-between-anusha-and-akrun).

Comment: `attributes(h1) <- c(attributes(hp[[1]]),attributes(hp[[2]]))`  May be this would be close enough?  Looking at the `str(h1)# ts [1:100, 1] -0.516 1.101 -0.756 0.786 0.926 ...
 - attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Series 1"`

Comment: @akrun Thanks. This works. Please add this as an answer and perhaps an explanation on using attributes. I was confused by the .. ..$ .. .. $ and didnt know how to access that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried using that as well but then converting tsp fractions to numbers 1997.250 , so that it can be put in the form start(1997, n) was posing a problem.(Then I could do ts(hp, start = c(tsp[1], n) frequency = 12) to get time attribute again. And tsp(h1) <- tsp(x) . wasnt working either. Any improvements regarding these methods ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha Sorry, I am not following it.  Could you update the code in the post so that others could also contribute.

Comment: @akrun Was the updated question clear ? You posted an answer but was deleted before getting to read it properly. Any suggestions regarding use of tsp or converting tsp fractions to proper time string ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha I deleted it after reading your comment about that is not working.  So, I thought my solution is not working properly. Right now, I am busy.  I will try to have a look at it later.

Comment: @akrun I was referring to the other methods which I had tried since you mentioned use of attributes(*tsp) because I have been trying various approaches. If you can help with the updates added to the question regarding them, it will be of great assistance. Your answer solved a long time problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anusha I undeleted my answer.  I couldn't get errors for `tsp(h1) <- tsp(x)` Is it some other time series?.  Also, in last code, what is `tsp1`; ie. `h1.ts <- ts(h1, start =c(tsp1, n), frequency = tsp[3])`

Comment: @akrun Thats a typo. Even though I typed tsp[1], showing as tsp1. I am just trying to use tsp as a vector where the first component is start date, second is end date and third component is frequency. To get the starting month for monthly series, would like to convert e.g 1990.250 to 1990/4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the info provided, I guess you can try:

```
 h1 <- hp$cycle
 str(h1)
 #Time-Series [1:100] from 1990 to 1998: -0.516 1.101 -0.756 0.786 0.926 ...
 attributes(h1)
 #$tsp
 #[1] 1990.00 1998.25   12.00

 #$class
 #[1] "ts"
```

If you look at the `str(hp)`, it is a list of 10 elements. To access the attributes of different elements, you can use `attributes` or `attr`.  For example:

```
 attr(hp$cycle, "tsp")
 #[1] 1990.00 1998.25   12.00
```

Or

```
  attributes(hp$cycle)[["tsp"]] #
 #[1] 1990.00 1998.25   12.00
```

To get the whole `attributes` for the list element

```
 attributes(hp$cycle)
 #$tsp
 #[1] 1990.00 1998.25   12.00

 #$class
 #[1] "ts"
```

Using `c` concatenates the attributes from different list elements and keep the list structure

```
 attributes(h1) <- c(attributes(hp$cycle), attributes(hp$trend))
 str(h1)
 #ts [1:100, 1] -0.516 1.101 -0.756 0.786 0.926 ...
 #- attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1990 1998 12
 #- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 # ..$ : NULL
 #..$ : chr "Series 1"

 tsp(h1)
 #[1] 1990.00 1998.25   12.00
 tsp(h1) <- tsp(x) #no errors here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `start`, `end` and `time`:

```
  start(c1)
 [1] 1990    1

  end(c1)
 [1] 1998    4

  time(c1)
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug
1990 1990.000 1990.083 1990.167 1990.250 1990.333 1990.417 1990.500 1990.583
1991 1991.000 1991.083 1991.167 1991.250 1991.333 1991.417 1991.500 1991.583
1992 1992.000 1992.083 1992.167 1992.250 1992.333 1992.417 1992.500 1992.583
1993 1993.000 1993.083 1993.167 1993.250 1993.333 1993.417 1993.500 1993.583
1994 1994.000 1994.083 1994.167 1994.250 1994.333 1994.417 1994.500 1994.583
1995 1995.000 1995.083 1995.167 1995.250 1995.333 1995.417 1995.500 1995.583
1996 1996.000 1996.083 1996.167 1996.250 1996.333 1996.417 1996.500 1996.583
1997 1997.000 1997.083 1997.167 1997.250 1997.333 1997.417 1997.500 1997.583
1998 1998.000 1998.083 1998.167 1998.250                                    
          Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
1990 1990.667 1990.750 1990.833 1990.917
1991 1991.667 1991.750 1991.833 1991.917
1992 1992.667 1992.750 1992.833 1992.917
1993 1993.667 1993.750 1993.833 1993.917
1994 1994.667 1994.750 1994.833 1994.917
1995 1995.667 1995.750 1995.833 1995.917
1996 1996.667 1996.750 1996.833 1996.917
1997 1997.667 1997.750 1997.833 1997.917
1998
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal but that doesnt help assign colnames as the dimension is still 1.

Comment: It is not a matrix, so you cannot assign column names.

Comment: @Anusha - There are no columns to assign the names to.  Are you trying to convert it to a matrix and then assign colnames?  You probably want to strip the attributes and build the matrix

Comment: I want to use the attributes information in the list object and convert it to a ts object of dimensions 2 so that colnames can be assigned from within the list object or outside.

Comment: Please provide a visible example of the desired result

Comment: @Anusha, a ts object is a vector.

Comment: Please refer to the last part of question, which I think can be done with attributes(c1) <- attributes(hp$x). Then colnames can be allocated to the object. Can you suggest how to allocate colnames using the series name information within the list ?

Comment: @Pascal Yes, so we add a column of date or convert to zoo so that colnames can be used. Here since that attribute is already there, want to use that rather than cbinding with date column or making it a zoo object.

Comment: @Anusha, please provide an **explicit** desired result, as suggested by Richard Scriven.

Comment: @RichardScriven I hope the question is clearer now.  Can you suggest how to access the name of series from the attributes part ? hp$x ... chr : "Series 1" ?

Comment: I think just `colnames(hp$x)` or `dimnames(hp$x)[[2]]` or `attr(hp$x,"dimnames")[[2]]` if I got what you want (but probably not).

Comment: @nicola Thanks. Thats helpful for extracting from the attributes. Edited the question to highlight the basic problem of naming a time series.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to create an n x 1 monthly `ts` series with a name then:

```
xx <- ts(cbind(A = 1:5), start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)
```

We can now refer to it by name:

```
xx[, "A"]
```

We can extract various components like this:

```
xx[2] # second point
xx[2, 1] # second point with name
xx[2, "A"] # same

start(xx) # start time
time(xx)[1]

end(xx) # end time
time(xx)[NROW(xx)]

time(xx) # times
c(time(xx))

frequency(xx)

cycle(xx) # months as a ts series
c(cycle(xx)) # plain

floor(time(xx)) # years as a ts series
c(floor(time(xx)))
```

We can convert `yy` below to an n x 1 series with a name:

```
yy <- ts(1:5, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 12)

dim(yy) <- c(length(yy), 1)
colnames(yy) <- "A"

yy[2, 1] # get second point with name
```

**Added** If we have:

```
xx <- ts(cbind(A = 1:5), start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)
```

and attributes get stripped:

```
xx2 <- c(xx)
```

then we can do this:

```
xx[] <- xx2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I start with the series defined like this but some functions strip the ts properties and the question is how to reallocate them. Good to know the dim() method.

Comment: See Added part at the end.

Comment: Could you please give a little detail on how xx[] stores time info ? This is new concept for me.

Comment: Is the dim() method working by adding a dummy column ?

Comment: `xx[]<-whatever` replaces the data part  of  `xx`  with whatever.  The attributes of xx are unchanged.  `dim` as shown reshapes the data component into a column column matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the desired output. Hope this helps. Please show the desired output.

```
newdf<-as.data.frame(hp$x)
colnames(newdf)
[1] "Series 1"
```

Comment: Judging from the confusion in all the comments, I'm guessing this is not the desired output.