# Attribute name to univariate time series object in R and ts

Tags: r, datetime

I´m reading a CSV file with a structure similar to

```
ref_date;   value
2017-01-31;  123123
2017-02-28;   938384
2017-03-30;   54536
```

so it has a monthly frequency. After giving up converting the dates on the ref_value column, I decided to use directly a conversion to ts:

```
df = read.csv(data_file, sep=';', header=T)
df_ts = ts(df$value, frequency=12, start=c(2017,1))
```

and now I´m trying to do a linear regression with `lm`, but as my time series has no names,

```
names(df_ts)
NULL
```

how can I either attribute names to the `ts` object or do a linear regression on it?

Comment: When you say that you gave up converting the dates in ref_value is that because you were having trouble getting them into a date format that you wanted? If I use `as.Date(ref_date)` to make a new ref_date, I can use `lm()` with that variable.

Comment: Sure, but then when I have to convert to a ts object, this Date column is not useful, I have to add the frequency anyway, and now the ts object is a mts object, what usually pose more problems later.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you then.

Comment: [this might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904474/how-to-extract-time-attributes-for-a-univariate-time-series?rq=1)